# What is 'Rd' in ST eDesignSuite?

Tags: boost

I'm trying to simulate my DC to DC boost converter in ST Microelectronics eDesignSuite.

There are some input parameters that need to be entered:

- Vin: 12V
- Vout: 36V, 100mA

What is `Rd` used for? It's this I am not getting.

[image]

[eDesignSuite suite link](https://eds.st.com/console/#/app/led/ic_led_catalogs/filter/%5B%5D/selected/led5000:floating%20boost)

Comment: Slope resistance of the diode. Will be in the diode datasheet.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Rd parameter is the dynamic resistance of the LED diode in this case. You can use I-V curves to calculate the Rd parameter.

[Here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva253a/snva253a.pdf?ts=1686224143061) on page 6 you can find more information about this parameter.

[image]